# How to set up a front end for AWS DBs without using the Internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-connection, frontend

On AWS, I know how to set up a web server with inbound rules allowing HTTP and HTTPS and a database security group that only connect to the web server. The issue is I need to create a front end to manage the databases *without* using Internet access - this will be internal only and precludes the use of a public IP / public DNS. Does anyone know how I would do this?

To further elaborate, some of our AWS accounts are for internal use only - we can log in to the console, use CygWin to SSH in, see what's there, etc. But these accounts are for development purposes, and in a large enterprise such as this one, these are not allowed an IGW. So - no inbound Internet access is allowed. How do I create an app (e.g., phpMyAdmin type) in which our manager can easily view and edit the data in the database given the restriction that this must be done without inbound Internet access?

Comment: you can use dynamo db service if want to use nosql database with UI and can manage using aws console.

Comment: No - I need a relational database. It has to support triggers and updates to linked tabled. Does a UI exist for RDS? That's what I need, really, when I refer to a front end - I need a good, user friendly UI.

Answer (score 0):

host your database on one EC2 and also upload your front end there. your database will be running on locally on EC2 and you can connect front end to database. where database will not have public DNS it will running locally you can access only using SSH and front end script.

you check this official documentation from aws : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.WorkingWithRDSInstanceinaVPC.html

for frontend script you can use https://www.adminer.org/ which is one file database management system. one simple file is there using this make connection to locally running database on EC2

Comment: no worries and you can comment down for more help..happy to help

Comment: If you can connect with SSH the machine is exposed to the Internet. The question is about accessing the database without inbound internet. The ways to do that is private subnet in VPC and Direct Access or VPN to a server in a public subnet of the VPC.

Comment: we can put one ec2 in private subnet and another onpublic so from public ec2 to private and using vpn both way we access it with inboud internet

Comment: Actually, the database management system mentioned above (https://www.adminer.org/) is insecure, with an expired cert, and therefore not allowed by our company. Any other ideas for a DB management system? Where can I read about how to actually implement and use one? Also, I also am not seeing how "connecting using a VPN" helps - can you explain? 
Please note that NO public subnets are allowed in this account.

Comment: @lorena here i am sharing link to setup your requirement on aws : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.WorkingWithRDSInstanceinaVPC.html

Comment: @lorena you can use phpmyadmin only instead of using anything adminer is there and phpmyadmin.here sharing documentation to setup mysql on aws RDS https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_MySQL.html

Answer (score 0):

Host your database on RDS inside a VPC and create a VPN connection between your client network and your VPC.

Comment: Hosting on RDS inside a VPC still doesn't solve how to manage the database - I have a DB on RDS in place already, with an SG that allows only my web server as inbound. However, what I typically use doesn't work because it relies on Apache / phpMyAdmin / Internet to serve up the DB management system via HTTP.  I want a reader-friendly front end from which to actually manage the DB system without having Internet access.

Comment: I need a good UI that doesn't rely on Internet access, in other words.

Comment: A VPC and VPN precisely allows for that - run a web app on an EC2 instance that is not exposed to the internet (no public IP address and no internet gateway are needed)

Comment: How? That was my question from the beginning. I'm used to opening HTTP and HTTPS for web servers - so what ports do I open in this case, what web app could I use for this, how do I actually view and manage it without the use of the Internet browser, etc.?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/vpn/ and https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/  No change neede don your Security Group.  This is a network configuration